# Expo Camera only opening once with React Navigation

Tags: reactjs, camera, navigation, native, expo

I set the Expo camera to open on the middle tab with react navigation. However, the camera only opens when I click on that tab the first time. If I switch off of it and go back it's just a black screen. Also the take a picture button is not there. (I am new with react native and kinda coding as a whole)

```
'use strict';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { Camera, Permissions } from 'expo';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    Dimensions,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    TouchableOpacity,
    View,
    Button
} from 'react-native';


class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class CameraView extends React.Component {
  state = {
    hasCameraPermission: null,
    type: Camera.Constants.Type.back,
  };

  async componentWillMount() {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
    this.setState({ hasCameraPermission: status === 'granted' });
  }
  render() {
     const { hasCameraPermission } = this.state;
    if (hasCameraPermission === null) {
      return <View />;
    } else if (hasCameraPermission === false) {
      return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
    } else {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Camera style={{ flex: 1 }} type={this.state.type}>
            <View
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                flexDirection: 'row',
              }}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={{
                  flex: 0.1,
                  alignSelf: 'flex-end',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                }}
                onPress={() => {
                  this.setState({
                    type: this.state.type === Camera.Constants.Type.back
                      ? Camera.Constants.Type.front
                      : Camera.Constants.Type.back,
                  });
                }}>
                <Text
                  style={{ fontSize: 18, marginBottom: 10, color: 'white' }}>
                  {' '}Flip{' '}
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </Camera>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
}

class SettingsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Settings!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}


export default createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
  Camera:CameraView,
  Settings: SettingsScreen
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        top: 250
    },

    capture: {
        flex: 0,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderRadius: 5,
        padding: 15,
        paddingHorizontal: 20,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        margin: 20
    }

});
```

Answer (score 23):

With react navigation 5.x

```
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';

export const CameraView = (props) => {
    const isFocused = useIsFocused();
    return (
       <View>
         { isFocused && <RNCamera  />  }
       </View>
     )
}
```

[useIsFocused Documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-is-focused/)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Can be the 'Accepted answer'

Answer (score 13):

I had some issue.

This code solved it:

```
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';

function MyComponent() {
  const isFocused = useIsFocused()
  
  return (
    <View>
      { isFocused && <RNCamera />  }
    </View>
  )
}
```

#### Old navigation

```
import { withNavigationFocus } from 'react-navigation'

render() {
    const { isFocused } = this.props
    return (
       <View>
         { isFocused && <RNCamera  ... />  }
       </View>
     )
}


export default withNavigationFocus(Camera)
```

Comment: I was able to do this with `import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';`

and `const isFocused = useIsFocused()` instead.

Comment: @ScottJodoin Thank you. Updated example with a never navigation.

Answer (score 7):

To make this work you need to:

1.

```
import { NavigationEvents } from 'react-navigation';
```

2. 

```
state = { loaded: true }
```

3. 

```
render() {
    const { loaded } = this.state;
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
            <NavigationEvents
             onWillFocus={payload => this.setState({loaded: true})}
             onDidBlur={payload => this.setState({loaded: false})}/>
            <View style={styles.cameraArea}>
            {loaded && (
                <Camera
                 type={Camera.Constants.Type.back}
                 ref={ref => {
                     this.camera = ref;
                }}
              />
              )}          
            </View>
```

The idea is to hide this camera view (onDidBlur-> loaded: false), then when you come back (onWillFocus is triggered and change loaded to true). When render() function is called it will show the `<Camera />` again.
If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me. ( Navigation 5.x )
if you are using a different screen for CAMERA, you can easy unmount the screen when moving to another.

> Reason of this behavior : Only one Camera preview can be active at any
> given time. If you have multiple screens in your app, you should
> unmount Camera components whenever a screen is unfocused.

```
<Stack.Screen name="camera" component={CameraScreen} options={{unmountOnBlur: true}}/>
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Documentation Link :  https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/camera/

Thanks.

Comment: This is the easiest fix and works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

I got it working by using NavigationEvents to determine if the tab is in focus and from there mount and unmount the camera. This also frees up the camera, if you need to use it in another screen. Here is what I would do in your example:

```
    import { NavigationEvents } from 'react-navigation';
    ...
    class CameraView extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
       super(props) 
       this.state = {
         hasCameraPermission: null,
         type: Camera.Constants.Type.back,
         isFocused:true
       };
      }

      ...

      render(){
       //...your existing if's
       } if(this.state.isFocused === false){
         return (
              <NavigationEvents
                    onWillFocus={payload => {
                        //console.log("will focus", payload);
                        this.setState({isFocused:true})
                    }}
                    onDidBlur={payload => {
                        //console.log('did leave',payload)
                        this.setState({isFocused:false})
                    }}
                />
         )
       }
       } else {
          return (
           <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Camera style={{ flex: 1 }} type={this.state.type}>
               <NavigationEvents
                    onWillFocus={payload => {
                        //console.log("will focus", payload);
                        this.setState({isFocused:true})
                    }}
                    onDidBlur={payload => {
                        //console.log('did leave',payload)
                        this.setState({isFocused:false})
                    }}
                />
          //...the rest of your camera code
      }
```

I hope it works for you as well

Answer (score 2):

I solved it using the hook `useIsFocused` from `react-navigation/native`. I tested it on Android, iOS and Web

```
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';

...

const isFocused = useIsFocused();

...

return (
    isFocused && (
      <Camera
        ref={(ref) => {
          camera = ref;
        }}
        onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
        style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
      />
    )
  );
```

Comment: I tried to incorporate the same method in my application, however, I am getting an error, `Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside a screen in a navigator`. Any Idea what's wrong and how to go about fixing this?

Answer (score 2):

in Expo react native

```
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';
    
const isFocused = useIsFocused();

{isFocused &&
        <Camera
            type={type}
            onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            flashMode={flash}
            zoom={zoom}
        />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RN Expo with React Navigation - Tab Navigator.

Then just use `unmountOnBlur` - [unmountOnBlur Documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#unmountonblur)

This will force the camera to unmount on every navigation focus changes.